# Get the key attribute in child component when using v-for in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

According to the VueJS documentation I have to pass a `:key` attribute which is a unique identifier for the component.

I have the following component iterator.

```
<line-reactive v-for="(chart, index) in chartcfg" :index="index" :key="chart.id"></line-reactive>
```

How can I access the `:key` attribute inside `LineReactive` (the child component)?

When I'm in my `LineReactive` component and do `this.key` it returns `undefined`

Comment: You can technically access the child's key value from within the child component via `this.$vnode.key`. Might be bad practice.